# Quantlib: Getting error trying to price a Swap

Tags: derivatives, swaps, python, quantlib

I have bootstrapped my curve based on end-of-day data for **24th Nov, 2017**

I am then using that to price a off-market swap as below:

```
swap = VanillaSwap(VanillaSwap.Payer, 10000.0,
                       fixed_schedule,
                       fixed_coupon/100,
                       Thirty360(),
                       floating_schedule,
                       index,
                       0.0, # <-- libor fixing
                       Actual360())
```

My swap details are:-

```
Valuation date: 27th Nov, 2017
Fixed_coupon = 2.2575
Maturity Date = 27th Nov, 2027
float freq = Period(3, Months)
fixed freq = Period(6, Months)
```

When I call the below:-

```
swap.NPV()
```

I get : **{Runtime error} 2nd leg: Missing Euribor3M Actual/360 fixing for November 23rd, 2017**

Does this mean I have to pass in a libor fixing when I create my VanillaSwap object?

Comment: I am facing the same issue as the one mentioned above. However, I created a schedule date object, based on the issue date, to get the previous date from today's date automatically. For a specific FloatingRate object, when I am trying to get the clean price it fails with the issue message. Is there a way to check the date when I am adding the fixing avoid it or correct the fixing date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to pass an Euribor fixing because your coupon is fixing in the past with respect to the valuation date and thus its rate can't be forecast on the interest-rate curve.  However, it's not passed through the construtor argument you have commented in your code; that one is used to pass any additional spread (for instance, if the floating leg swap were to pay Euribor plus 10 bps).

The way to store a past fixing is through the `index` instance. You can do it as

```
index.addFixing(Date(23,November,2017), rate);
```

after which it will be available to all `Euribor3M` instances.